# Unexpected round behaviour of Numpy float32

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, ieee-754

I am trying to understand how numpy handles the float32 datatype.

The following code produces 0.25815687

```
print(np.float32(0.2581568658351898).astype(str)) # 0.25815687
```

But an online float converter https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html gives 0.2581568658351898193359375, Is Numpy doing something special when printing the single-precision float or there is something I missed?
[Online converter result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejBvX.png)

Comment: To my understanding, when a float is converted to string in python, it is rounded by default to 8 decimals. How to change this behavior, I don't know from the top of my head. Other than the rounding, I don't see any differences.

Comment: Async Z, So "0.25815687: is unexpected.  What did you expect?

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica  I get 0.258156865835.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Numpy doing something special when printing the single-precision float or there is something I missed?

0.2581568658351898 is not exactly encodable as a 32-bit float.
The closest is `0.2581568658351898193359375` or `0x1.085a46p-2`

When `0.2581568658351898193359375` is printed with reduced precision, the result is `0.25815687`

---

```
0.2581568 658351898            Source code
0.2581568 658351898193359375   True value
0.2581568 7                    Output
```

Comment: Exactly, I thought .`astype(str)` would print with full precision. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @AsyncZ: Full precision isn't a very practical choice, since it can contain hundreds of digits (especially for double precision). For example for single precision, `2.350988561514728583455765982071533026645717985517980855365926236850006129930346077117064851336181163787841796875E-38` is an exactly representable value.

Comment: The closest value to 0.2581568658351898 that can be exactly represented as a 32bit float is 0.2581568658351898193359375.  Rounding this to 0.25815687 is wrong if the "round to nearest even" (aka "bankers' rounding") rule is used, but correct if the pure "round to nearest" rule is used.

Comment: @Andrew "Rounding this to 0.25815687 is wrong" is unclear.  _Bankers' rounding_ is usually round to nearest, _ties_ to even. Since 0.2581568_658351898193359375 is closer to 0.2581568_7 than 0.2581568_6, 0.2581568_7 is correct.

Comment: @AsyncZ with 32-bit floating point, printing more than 9 significant decimal places is never needed to round-trip the number (i. e. read back the text and get the same 32-bit floating point value).

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica  Depends on who you ask; to me, this IS a tie.  The SI standard that I learned is showcased here: "Example #4 - Round 24.8514 to three significant figures. Look at the fourth digit. It is a 5, so now you must also look at the third digit. It is 8, an even number, so you simply drop the 5 and the figures that follow it. The original number becomes 24.8. (rule #3 above)" --https://www.chemteam.info/SigFigs/Rounding.html (if the 5 is insignificant, then surely the 1 is way too insignificant).  :-)

Comment: @Andrew Consider this [bankers' rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_to_even).   IEEE 754 supports [Round to nearest, ties to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Roundings_to_nearest).

Comment: @Andrew Since you mention SI specifically, see also https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-811/nist-guide-si-appendix-b-conversion-factors#B71, and in particular the wording about ties (emphasis mine): "If the digits to be discarded begin with a 5 **and all of the following digits are 0**, the digit preceding the 5 is unchanged if it is even and increased by 1 if it is odd. (Note that this means that the final digit is always even.)"

Comment: @Mark Dickinson The problem with that method is it will skew the statistical/aggregate results upwards.  But if you have confidence is those very insignificant digits then that method does make sense, like I said, it depends on who you ask (or on the context).  See "if you treated each first nonsignificant 5 in the same way, you would be over- or understating the value of the rounded number, thus accumulating round-off error." --https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/04%3A_The_Basics_of_Chemistry/4.06%3A_Significant_Figures_and_Rounding

Comment: @Andrew: Actually, no. Under reasonable assumptions about the uniformity of distribution of input values, the NIST/SI method I linked to (which is the same as the IEEE 754 roundTiesToEven method) _eliminates_ bias - indeed, that's the whole point of it, and the reason it's called "statistician's rounding" (among many other names). In contrast, the method you're proposing has a towards-zero bias (5/10 of values - those with "rounding digit" 0 through 4 - round towards zero; 4/10 round away from zero, and the remaining 1/10 round either towards or away from  zero depending on parity).

Comment: OK, so if they ask you it is "right"--depends on who you ask/context, like I said.  You can scour the web and "correct" those who disagree, I guess--not sure what else I can tell you.

Comment: @Andrew The chemteam.info/SigFigs/Rounding.html is the bias rounding.  The rounding modes Mark Dickinson   and I linked are not biased.  If two folks with heavy math background cannot convince, perhaps a posted question is in order?

Comment: I still say it depends on context--pluses and misuses to both.  done

Answer (score 0):

You can force the number of digits to be printed using f-strings

```
print(f"{np.float32(0.2581568658351898):.25f}")
```

where `:.25f` tells the interpreter to print the value as a floating point number with 25 decimal digits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I thought `.astype(str)` would print with full precision. That's what I missed :)